# How to perform current tax rate selection using just one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my tax-rate table "history", where `start_date` and `end_date` represent the time span where the `value` applies (i.e. no tax before 1972-12-31 23:59:59, current tax 22.00 starting from 2013-10-01 00:00:00):

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| value | start_date          | end_date            |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| NULL  | NULL                | 1972-12-31 23:59:59 |
| 12.00 | 1973-01-01 00:00:00 | 1977-02-07 23:59:59 |
| 14.00 | 1973-02-08 00:00:00 | 1980-07-02 23:59:59 |
| 15.00 | 1980-11-01 00:00:00 | 1982-08-04 23:59:59 |
| 18.00 | 1982-08-05 00:00:00 | 1988-07-31 23:59:59 |
| 19.00 | 1988-08-01 00:00:00 | 1997-09-30 23:59:59 |
| 20.00 | 1997-10-01 00:00:00 | 2011-09-16 23:59:59 |
| 21.00 | 2011-09-17 00:00:00 | 2013-09-30 23:59:59 |
| 22.00 | 2013-10-01 00:00:00 | NULL                |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

How to perform a single query, getting the correct value?

- `NULL` for any date before 1973-01-01 00:00:00
- `value` for any date between `start_date` and `end_date`
- `22.00` for any present or future date

This would break the last condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM tax_rate
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

This would break the first condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM tax_rate
WHERE '1972-01-01' >= start_date
    AND ('1972-01-01' <= end_date OR end_date IS NULL)
ORDER BY end_date IS NULL DESC, end_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I'm quite sure this is a common problem, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly compare to `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tax_rate
WHERE (NOW() >= start_date or start_date is null) AND
      (NOW() <= end_date or end_date is null);
```

However, because your rates are non-overlapping and there are no gaps, you can just get the last one based on the `start_date`:

```
select *
from tax_rate
where NOW() >= start_date or start_date is null
order by coalesce(start_date, '1900-01-01') desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Your first query fails in selecting the `NULL` rate for (say) 1965-01-01.

Comment: @gremo . . . How does it fail?  The first clause `(NOW() >= start_date or start_date is null)` evaluates to true for the first row in the table because `start_date` is null, the second clause `(NOW() <= end_date or end_date is null)` evaluates to true because the date is before `'1972-12-31 23:59:59'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `COALESCE` that change `NULL` into *value*

```
SELECT *
  FROM tax_rate
 WHERE NOW() BETWEEN COALESCE(start_date, '1800-01-01') AND COALESCE(end_date, '2100-01-01')
```